# TextEdit Crashes on New Document (SIGSEGV)

Tags: macos, crash, textedit

I can't even create a new text document in TextEdit, though I can open any existing one. Whenever I click "New Document", I get the following crash report:

```
Process:         TextEdit [23534]
Path:            /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
Identifier:      com.apple.TextEdit
Version:         1.8 (301)
Build Info:      TextEdit-301000000000000~50
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [142]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2013-02-11 10:34:09.388 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          8742 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           659
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  32044 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   6
Anonymous UUID:                      A2155AA2-47C6-95D0-8B64-0CC17A6CF305

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000007

VM Regions Near 0x7:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010f1c0000-000000010f1de000 [  120K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit

Application Specific Information:
Performing @selector(newDocument:) from sender NSMenuItem 0x7fbbc4422990

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bcbc1b1 __NSFontTypefaceInfoDeallocation + 519
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bcbbf80 -[__NSFontTypefaceInfo dealloc] + 25
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8ad62230 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 464
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89727342 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 34
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff89782ac9 __NSArrayEnumerate + 713
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b9cafe6 -[NSInspectorBar _tile] + 600
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b9c9ffe -[NSInspectorBar _update] + 243
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b9c980f -[NSInspectorBar setVisible:] + 335
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b9c941f -[NSTextView(NSSharing) setUsesInspectorBar:] + 253
9   com.apple.TextEdit              0x000000010f1d1157 0x10f1c0000 + 69975
10  com.apple.TextEdit              0x000000010f1c54c9 0x10f1c0000 + 21705
11  com.apple.TextEdit              0x000000010f1c516f 0x10f1c0000 + 20847
12  com.apple.TextEdit              0x000000010f1c421b 0x10f1c0000 + 16923
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bc65062 -[NSWindowController _windowDidLoad] + 448
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bc363ba -[NSWindowController window] + 114
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bc76c59 -[NSWindowController showWindow:] + 53
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b9c1476 -[NSDocument showWindows] + 103
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b9bf62f -[NSDocumentController openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:] + 461
18  com.apple.TextEdit              0x000000010f1c64b1 0x10f1c0000 + 25777
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b9bf41e -[NSDocumentController newDocument:] + 39
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bc01a59 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 342
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bd3744c -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 406
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bd3713a -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 133
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bd35f78 -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] + 711
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bd35e8f -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] + 478
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bd35283 -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:] + 829
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bbf2243 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4480
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bb082fa -[NSApplication run] + 636
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8baaccb6 NSApplicationMain + 869
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff89f507e1 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89ed86d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cd7eec _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cd7cb3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cc2171 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89ed8d16 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff91cfbdea _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 883
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff91cfb9ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89ed86d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cd7eec _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cd7cb3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cc2171 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89ed86d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cd7eec _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cd7cb3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cc2171 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff89ed86d6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cd7eec _pthread_workq_return + 25
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cd7cb3 _pthread_wqthread + 412
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86cc2171 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fbbc414ea60  rcx: 0x00007fff76487e01  rdx: 0x0000000000000007
  rdi: 0x00007fff76490610  rsi: 0x0000000000000002  rbp: 0x00007fff50a3e500  rsp: 0x00007fff50a3e4e0
   r8: 0x000000000000002e   r9: 0xffffffffffffffff  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x00000000203db78e
  r12: 0x000000000000000e  r13: 0x000000000000000f  r14: 0x00007fff76495f70  r15: 0x00007fbbc241a660
  rip: 0x00007fff8bcbc1b1  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000000000007
Logical CPU: 2

Binary Images:
       0x10f1c0000 -        0x10f1ddff7  com.apple.TextEdit (1.8 - 301)  /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
    0x7fff6edc0000 -     0x7fff6edf493f  dyld (210.2.3)  /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff85e60000 -     0x7fff85e61fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (59)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff860be000 -     0x7fff860c2fff  libpam.2.dylib (20)  /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
    0x7fff860d1000 -     0x7fff8611bff7  libGLU.dylib (8.6.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
    0x7fff86158000 -     0x7fff8617dff7  libc++abi.dylib (24.4)  /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff86180000 -     0x7fff86201fff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 707.3)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff86399000 -     0x7fff863adfff  libGL.dylib (8.6.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
    0x7fff863d8000 -     0x7fff86465ff7  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff86466000 -     0x7fff86475ff7  libxar.1.dylib (105)  /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
    0x7fff86707000 -     0x7fff86709fff  libquarantine.dylib (52)  /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff8670c000 -     0x7fff867a6fff  com.apple.CoreSymbolication (3.0 - 87)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication
    0x7fff86900000 -     0x7fff8693dfe7  libGLImage.dylib (8.6.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff8698e000 -     0x7fff86995fff  libcopyfile.dylib (89)  /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff86996000 -     0x7fff869edff7  com.apple.ScalableUserInterface (1.0 - 1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ScalableUserInterface.framework/Versions/A/ScalableUserInterface
    0x7fff869ee000 -     0x7fff869efff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (220)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff869f0000 -     0x7fff86a0fff7  libresolv.9.dylib (51)  /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff86a10000 -     0x7fff86a65ff7  libTIFF.dylib (845)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
    0x7fff86ad8000 -     0x7fff86adefff  libmacho.dylib (829)  /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff86adf000 -     0x7fff86aeafff  libsystem_notify.dylib (98.5)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff86aeb000 -     0x7fff86aebfff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.8 - Accelerate 1.8)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff86aec000 -     0x7fff86aeefff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 23)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff86bf2000 -     0x7fff86c23ff7  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 184.4)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff86c99000 -     0x7fff86cc0fff  com.apple.framework.familycontrols (4.1 - 410)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
    0x7fff86cc1000 -     0x7fff86d8dfe7  libsystem_c.dylib (825.25)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff86d8e000 -     0x7fff86d90fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib (8.6.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x7fff86f61000 -     0x7fff87081fff  com.apple.desktopservices (1.7.2 - 1.7.2)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
    0x7fff87082000 -     0x7fff8749ffff  FaceCoreLight (2.4.1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/Versions/A/FaceCoreLight
    0x7fff874a0000 -     0x7fff874caff7  com.apple.CoreVideo (1.8 - 99.3)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff874cb000 -     0x7fff875c8ff7  libxml2.2.dylib (22.3)  /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff875c9000 -     0x7fff875f4fff  libxslt.1.dylib (11.3)  /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff875f5000 -     0x7fff875f9fff  libCGXType.A.dylib (324.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCGXType.A.dylib
    0x7fff8786f000 -     0x7fff8787cff7  com.apple.NetAuth (4.0 - 4.0)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff8787d000 -     0x7fff8787fff7  libunc.dylib (25)  /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff87929000 -     0x7fff87a9dfff  com.apple.CFNetwork (596.2.3 - 596.2.3)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff87b0e000 -     0x7fff87b64fff  com.apple.HIServices (1.20 - 417)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff87b65000 -     0x7fff87b6cfff  com.apple.NetFS (5.0 - 4.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff87b71000 -     0x7fff87b71ffd  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit (1.8 - 1.8)  /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
    0x7fff87b72000 -     0x7fff87e89ff7  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1037.3 - 1037.3)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff87f7b000 -     0x7fff87f8aff7  com.apple.opengl (1.8.6 - 1.8.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff87f93000 -     0x7fff87f9ffff  com.apple.CrashReporterSupport (10.8.2 - 415)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/Versions/A/CrashReporterSupport
    0x7fff883dd000 -     0x7fff883efff7  libz.1.dylib (43)  /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff883f0000 -     0x7fff883f1ff7  libremovefile.dylib (23.1)  /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff883f2000 -     0x7fff88722ff7  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.0 - 625)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
    0x7fff88723000 -     0x7fff88729fff  libGFXShared.dylib (8.6.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x7fff887aa000 -     0x7fff88812ff7  libc++.1.dylib (65.1)  /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff888ca000 -     0x7fff888cffff  libcache.dylib (57)  /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff888d0000 -     0x7fff8891cff7  libauto.dylib (185.1)  /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff889a2000 -     0x7fff889a7fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (30)  /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff889f4000 -     0x7fff889f5fff  liblangid.dylib (116)  /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x7fff88b11000 -     0x7fff88babfff  libvMisc.dylib (380.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff88d8a000 -     0x7fff88e8cfff  libJP2.dylib (845)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
    0x7fff88e8d000 -     0x7fff88e9bff7  libsystem_network.dylib (77.10)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff88ea7000 -     0x7fff88ec8fff  com.apple.Ubiquity (1.2 - 243.10)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Ubiquity.framework/Versions/A/Ubiquity
    0x7fff88ec9000 -     0x7fff88f4bfff  com.apple.Heimdal (3.0 - 2.0)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Versions/A/Heimdal
    0x7fff88f87000 -     0x7fff8902dff7  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (557.4 - 557.4)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff890c0000 -     0x7fff8912dfff  com.apple.datadetectorscore (4.0 - 269.1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCore
    0x7fff8912e000 -     0x7fff89133fff  com.apple.OpenDirectory (10.8 - 151.10)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
    0x7fff89134000 -     0x7fff8915cfff  libJPEG.dylib (845)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff89193000 -     0x7fff89418ff7  com.apple.RawCamera.bundle (4.03 - 676)  /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
    0x7fff89422000 -     0x7fff894f4ff7  com.apple.CoreText (260.0 - 275.16)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff8953a000 -     0x7fff8953afff  libkeymgr.dylib (25)  /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff89655000 -     0x7fff89698ff7  com.apple.bom (12.0 - 192)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Versions/A/Bom
    0x7fff896f7000 -     0x7fff898e0fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.8 - 744.12)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff898e1000 -     0x7fff898effff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60026)  /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff898f0000 -     0x7fff89946ff7  com.apple.opencl (2.1.20 - 2.1.20)  /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff89962000 -     0x7fff89a3cff7  com.apple.backup.framework (1.4.1 - 1.4.1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
    0x7fff89a3d000 -     0x7fff89aeefff  com.apple.LaunchServices (539.7 - 539.7)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff89b33000 -     0x7fff89b34ff7  libSystem.B.dylib (169.3)  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff89b35000 -     0x7fff89cbbfff  libBLAS.dylib (1073.4)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff89cbc000 -     0x7fff89e6afff  com.apple.QuartzCore (1.8 - 304.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
    0x7fff89e6b000 -     0x7fff89ec5fff  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (8.1 - 387.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff89ec6000 -     0x7fff89ee1ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2050.18.24)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff89ee2000 -     0x7fff89ee8ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.1)  /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff89f4e000 -     0x7fff89f51ff7  libdyld.dylib (210.2.3)  /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff8a0b3000 -     0x7fff8a24efef  com.apple.vImage (6.0 - 6.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff8a254000 -     0x7fff8a36dff7  com.apple.ImageIO.framework (3.2.0 - 845)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff8a3c0000 -     0x7fff8ad50c67  com.apple.CoreGraphics (1.600.0 - 324.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff8ad58000 -     0x7fff8ae7092f  libobjc.A.dylib (532.2)  /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff8ae71000 -     0x7fff8ae7fff7  libkxld.dylib (2050.18.24)  /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff8ae80000 -     0x7fff8ae8efff  com.apple.Librarian (1.1 - 1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Librarian.framework/Versions/A/Librarian
    0x7fff8af70000 -     0x7fff8af70fff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.7 - 19)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff8b425000 -     0x7fff8b446ff7  libCRFSuite.dylib (33)  /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x7fff8b447000 -     0x7fff8b466ff7  com.apple.ChunkingLibrary (2.0 - 133.2)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/Versions/A/ChunkingLibrary
    0x7fff8b46a000 -     0x7fff8b4c7fff  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio (4.1.0 - 4.1.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
    0x7fff8b4c8000 -     0x7fff8b517ff7  libFontRegistry.dylib (100)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff8b8a4000 -     0x7fff8b8b0fff  libCSync.A.dylib (324.6)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libCSync.A.dylib
    0x7fff8b8ea000 -     0x7fff8b9afff7  com.apple.coreui (2.0 - 181.1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
    0x7fff8b9bc000 -     0x7fff8c5e9ff7  com.apple.AppKit (6.8 - 1187.34)  /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff8c640000 -     0x7fff8c676fff  libsystem_info.dylib (406.17)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff8c746000 -     0x7fff8c74ffff  com.apple.CommerceCore (1.0 - 26)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
    0x7fff8c750000 -     0x7fff8c7b9fff  libstdc++.6.dylib (56)  /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff8c7ba000 -     0x7fff8cb16fff  com.apple.Foundation (6.8 - 945.11)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff8d0f3000 -     0x7fff8d129fff  com.apple.DebugSymbols (98 - 98)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DebugSymbols.framework/Versions/A/DebugSymbols
    0x7fff8d12a000 -     0x7fff8d1e7ff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.8.0 - 4.8.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff8d2da000 -     0x7fff8d3e5fff  libFontParser.dylib (84.5)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff8d3e6000 -     0x7fff8d3eaff7  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
    0x7fff8dcf2000 -     0x7fff8dcfdff7  com.apple.bsd.ServiceManagement (2.0 - 2.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
    0x7fff8dcfe000 -     0x7fff8dcfefff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (45 - 45)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff8dd05000 -     0x7fff8dd27ff7  com.apple.Kerberos (2.0 - 1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff8e4de000 -     0x7fff8e500ff7  libxpc.dylib (140.41)  /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff8e501000 -     0x7fff8e5fefff  libsqlite3.dylib (138.1)  /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff8e5ff000 -     0x7fff8e605fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.5.1 - 2.5.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff8e65c000 -     0x7fff8e92cfff  com.apple.security (7.0 - 55179.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff8e93f000 -     0x7fff8e990ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.12.2 - 1.12.2)  /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff8e9bd000 -     0x7fff8e9befff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (8)  /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff8e9dd000 -     0x7fff8e9e5ff7  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (379.32.1)  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff8e9e6000 -     0x7fff8e9f9ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0)  /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff8ea06000 -     0x7fff8ea86ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (332 - 341.1)  ...
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: 1. Quit TextEdit (if it's running). 
 2. In Finder, Open a new Finder window and navigate to
    ~/Library/Preferences/.
 3. Delete files with names starting com.apple.TextEdit.plist.
4. Launch TextEdit.

Comment: I did try this; there were 2 of them. I deleted both and relaunched; same problem.

Comment: That rules out the same problem I had with TextEdit crashing. Corrupted plist because I kept switching from iCloud to local SSD. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: If you use iCloud, you might also have a go at System Preferences->iCloud and uncheck Documents & Data from the sync list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > 0   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8bcbc1b1 __NSFontTypefaceInfoDeallocation + 519

NSFont is, perhaps unsurprisingly, the font handling part of Mac OS X.

Try launching Font Book (or your preferred font management app) and using it to detect and fix any font problems.

more things to try:

http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/troubleshoot-fonts-mac-os-x.html

http://blog.extensis.com/fonts/updated-font-management-best-practices-in-os-x-now-includes-apples-mountain-lion.php

http://www.jamapi.com/pr/fn/ (ymmv, exercise caution, etc. etc.)

Comment: When I click the `Al Bayan` font in Font Book, I get a similar crash

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by refreshing the font cache. Thanks a lot!